# Преобразование даты в текст по определенному формату

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

В таблицах БД нашей СРМ-ки дата хранится в очень странном формате: `YYYY-DD-MM` (и, да, это еще строка). Поступило задание залить в таблицу данные из другой БД, где дата хранится в подобающем ей формате `DATETIME2(YYYY-MM-DD)`.

Как конвертнуть дату в строку с изменением формата?

Comment: [FORMAT(value, yyyy-dd-MM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: Прошу прощения, что забыл указать версию - у нас 2008, насколько погуглил - в 2008 этой функции нет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой способ это воспользоваться функцией [**CONVERT**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Это выглядит вот так:

```
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = GETDATE()

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)
```

**Вот список допустимых шаблонов форматов даты:**

```
DECLARE @now datetime
SET @now = GETDATE()
select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 0) as output, 0 as style 
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 1), 1
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 2), 2
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 3), 3
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 4), 4
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 5), 5
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 6), 6
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 7), 7
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 8), 8
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 9), 9
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 10), 10
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 11), 11
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 12), 12
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 13), 13
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 14), 14
--С 15 по 19 отсутствуют
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 20), 20
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 21), 21
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 22), 22
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 23), 23
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 24), 24
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 25), 25
--С 26 по 99 отсутствуют
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 100), 100
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 101), 101
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 102), 102
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 103), 103
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 104), 104
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 105), 105
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 106), 106
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 107), 107
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 108), 108
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 109), 109
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 110), 110
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 111), 111
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 112), 112
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 113), 113
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 114), 114
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 120), 120
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 121), 121
--С 122 по 125 отсутствуют
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 126), 126
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 127), 127
--128, 129 отсутствуют
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 130), 130
union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 131), 131
order BY style
```

**И результат выполнения**

```
Sep 20 2017  1:06PM 0
09/20/17    1
17.09.20    2
20/09/17    3
20.09.17    4
20-09-17    5
20 Sep 17   6
Sep 20, 17  7
13:06:22    8
Sep 20 2017  1:06:22:423PM  9
09-20-17    10
17/09/20    11
170920  12
20 Sep 2017 13:06:22:423    13
13:06:22:423    14
2017-09-20 13:06:22 20
2017-09-20 13:06:22.423 21
09/20/17  1:06:22 PM    22
2017-09-20  23
13:06:22    24
2017-09-20 13:06:22.423 25
Sep 20 2017  1:06PM 100
09/20/2017  101
2017.09.20  102
20/09/2017  103
20.09.2017  104
20-09-2017  105
20 Sep 2017 106
Sep 20, 2017    107
13:06:22    108
Sep 20 2017  1:06:22:423PM  109
09-20-2017  110
2017/09/20  111
20170920    112
20 Sep 2017 13:06:22:423    113
13:06:22:423    114
2017-09-20 13:06:22 120
2017-09-20 13:06:22.423 121
2017-09-20T13:06:22.423 126
2017-09-20T13:06:22.423 127
29 ذو الحجة 1438  1:06:22:423PM 130
29/12/1438  1:06:22:423PM   131
```

### Но

Будьте аккуратны с форматом YYYY-MM-DD, он зависит от настроек языка. Лучший стандарт по ISO - YYYYMMDD. Более подробно можно прочитать [тут](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/05/date-format-inconsistency-yyyy-mm-dd-or-yyyymmdd-when-2007-04-10-is-4th-october.aspx), но на английском.

#### Что делать, если нет нужного формата

*Можно воспользоваться следующим методом:*

```
SELECT
      RIGHT('00'   + CAST(DATEPART(day,    GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) + '/' +
      RIGHT('00'   + CAST(DATEPART(month,  GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) + '/' +
      RIGHT('0000' + CAST(DATEPART(year,   GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)),4) + ' ' +
      RIGHT('00'   + CAST(DATEPART(hour,   GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
      RIGHT('00'   + CAST(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
      RIGHT('00'   + CAST(DATEPART(second, GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) AS ItalianDate
```

Как вы понимаете на больших объёмах это будет работать не очень быстро.

Начиная с SQL Server 2012 появилась встроенная функция [FORMAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS 'DateTime Result'
```

Больше вариантов по произвольному формированию даты можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/)

Answer (score -1):

declare @f sysname = '2016-13-12';

select cast( substring(@f, 1,4) + '.' + substring(@f,9,2) + '.' + substring(@f, 6,2) as date)

ну заместо @f ваш столбец, Isaac

а вот 
select FORMAT('2016-13-12', 'yyyy-dd-MM')

выдает

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.